# gather() in tidyr, two different codes, one is corrct and the other is wrong

Tags: r, tidyr

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/EDAWR")
library(EDAWR)
gather(population,key="year",value="population",`1995`:`2013`)
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `1995` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

`` gather(EDAWR::population,key="year",value="population",`1995`:`2013`) ``

I am writing to ask why the first code is incorrect but the second one is correct?
BTW, does the notation `EDAWR::population` the same as `population`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me both the code works the same way. I am guessing the reason why you are getting the error is because you have a dataframe called `population` in your global environment where the column 1995 is not present.

For example, if I create a temporary dataframe called `population` I can reproduce the same error.

```
population <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
gather(population,key="year",value="population",`1995`:`2013`)
```

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Column `1995` doesn't exist.

Here `population` dataframe is the one that we created which has only one column (`a`) hence, we get the error. Using `EDAWR::population` refers to the dataframe from `EDAWR` package.

Remove the `poulation` dataframe using `rm(population)` and I think both the code should work the same way. Also `gather` has been retired and replaced with `pivot_longer` now.